# How can i add list(image) field in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fields

I'm using **Drupal 7 + Ubercart**. Have to add a **field** with easy selecting from images **(52 logo images of producers)**, that are already uploaded and will be used every time, when i'm adding new product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Media module](https://drupal.org/project/media). From [media documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/media)

> Media provides a multimedia browser which allows a user to view and
>   search through all of the multimedia currently added to a site.

After enabling the module, go to your content type `Manage fields` page, and change the widget of your image field to `Media file selector`.

Screenshot for your field settings.
[image: screenshot]

Screenshot for Media browser
[image: screenshot2]